# Creating Metaplex metadata from an Anchor program?

Tags: anchor, metaplex, metadata

I want to create a token entangler that pushes the minting to the user instead of requiring pre-minting by the owner. For that, I'm creating an Anchor program that first mints a collection token and its metadata, before allowing holders of the original collection to entangle their token (transfer OG token + mint entangled version and create metadata).

My problem is that I keep getting a `NotEnoughAccountKeys` error.
My logs look like this for the failing instruction:

```
Program log: Instruction: Create Metadata Accounts v2
Program log: Error: NotEnoughAccountKeys
Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 3932 of 103222 compute units
Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: insufficient account keys for instruction
Program 6UnTeNe18TsxBPJfLYxRYUnWyUfALuxD1e23gMswxSN8 consumed 100710 of 200000 compute units
Program 6UnTeNe18TsxBPJfLYxRYUnWyUfALuxD1e23gMswxSN8 failed: insufficient account keys for instruction
```

The call that triggers this log is the following:

```
let original_metadata =
    Metadata::from_account_info(&ctx.accounts.original_collection_metadata).unwrap();

let authority_bump = *ctx.bumps.get("entangler_authority").unwrap();
let authority_seeds = &[AUTHORITY_SEED.as_bytes(), &[authority_bump]];
let authority_signer_seeds = &[&authority_seeds[..]];

// Mint the token
let mint_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
    ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
    MintTo {
        mint: ctx.accounts.entangled_collection_mint.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.entangler_authority.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx
            .accounts
            .entangled_collection_mint_token_account
            .to_account_info(),
    },
    authority_signer_seeds,
);
token::mint_to(mint_ctx, 1)?;

// Create metadata
invoke_signed(
    &create_metadata_accounts_v2(
        ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
        ctx.accounts.entangled_collection_metadata.key(),
        ctx.accounts.entangled_collection_mint.key(),
        ctx.accounts.entangler_authority.key(),
        ctx.accounts.signer.key(),
        ctx.accounts.entangler_authority.key(),
        original_metadata.data.name,
        original_metadata.data.symbol,
        original_metadata.data.uri,
        Some(vec![Creator {
            address: ctx.accounts.signer.key(),
            verified: true,
            share: 100,
        }]),
        royalties,
        false,
        true,
        None,
        None,
    ),
    &[
        ctx.accounts.entangled_collection_metadata.to_account_info(), // Metadata
        ctx.accounts.entangled_collection_mint.to_account_info(),     // Mint
        ctx.accounts.entangler_authority.to_account_info(),           // Mint authority
        ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),                        // Payer
        ctx.accounts.entangler_authority.to_account_info(),           // Update authority
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),                // System program
        ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),                          // Rent
    ],
    authority_signer_seeds,
)?;
```

Looking at metadata creation on an explorer, I can see that these are the correct accounts needed, other questions have similar accounts, I looked at Cardinal's code but I still can manage to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the error was setting the creator `verified` to `true`